# Using UIStackView with a UITextView with dynamic height

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, constraints

I just found out about UIStackView, and I'm trying to see if it can finally make it easier to lay out expanding content.

Specifically, I want to do the following:

```
|-- UITextView ------------|
| some dynamic text here,  |  I want the text view's height to change
| it could be short, or it |  depending on the height of the text
| could be tall            |  (set later, in code)
|-- UIView ----------------|
|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|  I want this view to expand to fill the 
|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|  vertical space.
|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|  
|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|  It should start right below the
|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|  bottom of the UITextView
|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|
|--------------------------|
```

I think I know how to do this with regular constraints. Is it possible to do with UIStackView? I might be understanding the purpose of UIStackView, but I would love to be able to create layouts like this more easily.

When I put both of these into a UIStackView, Interface builder says "Needs constraints for: Y position or height" for both views.

Comment: I'm also ok using a multi-line UILabel if that works better.

Comment: Only uncheck 'scrolling enable'

Comment: vote up for the pseudo-graphic effort

Answer (score 2):

Programmatically it looks like this:

```
@IBOutlet private var stackView: UIStackView! 
{
    didSet {
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(titleTextView)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(UIView())
    }
}

lazy var titleTextView: UITextView = 
{
    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    return textView
}()
```

You don’t need anything else for the UITextView to expand automatically. This shouldn’t complain about ambiguities.

Comment: You can add a stackview then inside that add a textview, then set scrollable false, it will automaticaly handle your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can add a stackview then inside that add a textview, then set scrollable false, it will automaticaly handle your problem

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the text height in textview add a height constraint on uitextview say 20 and when you calculate the height just change the height constraint.Give the below view constraint of top 0 from textview and you issue will be resolved.
Calculate height using this function

```
let height = string.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(CGFloat.max,textviewwidth), options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font!], context: nil).size.height
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an UILabel with lines = 0 instead of an UITextView.

Comment: that's not really an answer on question asked

Comment: it's actually a valid way to do it.